# Apache Alias - NextJS App linking to Angular App in seperate document root

Tags: angular, apache, httpd.conf

We have a NextJS App which is linking to our Angular App under the same primary domain but a separate document root. I have reviewed many help articles but cant seem to triage our issue.

Companydomain.com document root is (NextJS Site): /var/www/html/app-live/dist/out Angular App Document root is: /var/www/html/app-live/dist/en

I can navigate from NextJS site to the Angular site and get the correct angular page but when I link directly or refresh I get a 404.

I have modified the httpd.conf for the site as such

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName Companydomain.com
ServerAlias www.Companydomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app-live/dist/out"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

Alias /en/framesite/Bellas/103 /var/www/html/app-live/dist/en/framesite/Bellas/103
<Directory "/var/www/html/app-live/dist/en/store/Bellas/103/">
    RewriteEngine on
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Alias /en /var/www/html/app-live/dist/en

</VirtualHost>`
```

I have also run service httpd restart

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think youre trying to make a reverse proxy for your angular app from a subdirectory that is present in NEXTJS domain. The errors appearing are because of the issues of configuration. Check these things:

1. Build the angular app correctly.
2. Deploy this app to the correct location and double check it i.e  in your case it is/var/www/html/app-live/dist/en
3. Check again that all the files are present and none of them is deleted.
4. Also check that permission is given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution but it worked for my immediate needs.

I was able to truncate the aliased location file to  /var/www/html/app-live/dist/en/ and the pages resolved correctly

Alias /en/framesite/Bellas/103 /var/www/html/app-live/dist/en/